# Can't find Android's file "debug.keystore" on Windows 10

Tags: android

Android Studio 3.5, Windows 10.

I can't find `debug.keystore` file. I search in `c:\users\my_user\.android\` folder. But it not  find in this folder.

Comment: what is your main problem??

Comment: I want to check is some apk is sign my debug key

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio will create this file automatically if you run any app. If you have never ran an app then this file won't be generated.

Comment: I find them on path. It locate on avd install folder. In my case this is d:\Programs\Android\avd\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: So, did your find the debug keystore or not?